# how to check user is login in facebook in iphone setting or not ?

Tags: ios, autologin, facebook-sdk-3.0

if user is already login then don't open facebook login page  in IOS......
is there any API in facebook sdk to check this kind of  ?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    // Facebook SDK * login flow *
    // Attempt to handle URLs to complete any auth (e.g., SSO) flow.
    NSLog(@"we reach here");
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
        // Facebook SDK * App Linking *
        // For simplicity, this sample will ignore the link if the session is already
        // open but a more advanced app could support features like user switching.
        if (call.accessTokenData) {
            if ([FBSession activeSession].isOpen) {
                NSLog(@"we r here");
                NSLog(@"INFO: Ignoring app link because current session is open.");
            }
            else {
                [self handleAppLink:call.accessTokenData];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

i try this but it's not working for me